# Satellite image in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, layers, satellite

I would like to know if there is a satellite map for OpenLayers.

I made the following code:

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
  // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
  title: 'Stamen',
  // Again set this layer as a base layer
  type: 'base',
  visible: false,
  source: new ol.source.Stamen({
      layer: 'watercolor'
  })
}),
new ol.layer.Tile({
  // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
  title: 'Satelite',
  // Again set this layer as a base layer
  type: 'base',
  visible: false,
  source: new ol.source.Stamen({
      layer: 'terrain'
  })
}),
new ol.layer.Tile({
  // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
  title: 'OSM',
  // Again set this layer as a base layer
  type: 'base',
  visible: true,
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
})
```

And now I need an openlayers satellite map or something compatible with it.

Comment: OpenLayers examples use Bing https://openlayers.org/en/main/examples/preload.html and MapTiler https://openlayers.org/en/main/examples/layer-swipe.html but there are many other sources available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both maps that @Mike mentioned in his comment require API key. One possible satellite map is Esri's (ArcGIS) World Imagery:

```
var worldImagery = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
    maxZoom: 19
  })
});
```

Comment: Is this free for production? (including attributions)

Comment: You can check this here: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/terms-of-use.htm